# I would like to "FORCE" a click on the in-context paypal button (so I can hide it!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

Okay, basically I have a large-ish plugin for wordpress which has the ability to include multiple "payment" forms which direct the users to paypal for them to complete the order.

The problem is, its 100% necessary to keep our current form button.

Basically what I have now *KIND OF* works but it redirects the entire browser to the paypal site and it redirects me to some hermes to legacy or whatever page. So thats not good, but when I use the in-context javascript it works the way it should, but it changes my button to an ugly paypal button.

Here is some code:

This comes after I validate my form:

```
            /*
                Successful validation!

                Disable this callback and officially submit the form.
            */
            if (data.hasOwnProperty('ic')) {
                /*
                    if ajax response returns an ic property
                    then, create "HIDDEN" anchor tag
                    and apply paypal to it.

                    f = the current form
                */
                f.append($('<a href="#startpayment" id="xyz_begin_incontext" style="position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px;">Start In Context</a>'));

                paypal.checkout.setup(data.ic.id,{
                    container:document.getElementById("xyz_begin_incontext"),
                    environment:data.ic.environment.toLowerCase(),
                    click:function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });

                /*
                    Open modal
                */
                paypal.checkout.initXO();

                /*
                    Call .startFlow()
                */
                paypal.checkout.startFlow(data.ic.token);
            }
```

please do note that this DOES accomplish what I want, however, it doesn't open the paypal up in a popup window, it redirects the current page to the paypal.checkout.prefixUrl url, which would defeat the whole purpose of in-context...

Please someone tell me how to achieve what this does, while also maintaining my current styling on my button!

Thanks!
Russell

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting redirected to that hermes legacy page instead of checkoutnow. And it turns out for me that it was caused by having ITEMCATEGORY set to 'Digital'. Not sure if this will fix your issue, but nowhere anywhere had I seen anyone referencing paypal hermes_to_legacy except for you here, so I thought I should mention it.